# Where to store app state in Sveltekit when data is loaded and shared between nested layouts

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm new to Sveltekit and writing an app for tracking notes about books I'm reading. There is a list of book series, clicking one shows a list of volumes in that series, clicking one shows your notes for that volume.

I need to store: the list of series, which series is selected, the list of volumes, which volume is selected. Where do I store this?

What I've tried:

I have the pages setup as nested layouts, the top level loads series, a nested layout checks what's selected based on the route parameters and loads the volumes, and so on. My most nested route looks like this: `/series/[seriesId]/volumes/[volumeId]`, with a layout at each level to load/set what it can.

I tried putting state in `props` returned from `load` on my layout, but then I can't update it if I add a new series or volume, it seems to just wipe out my change next time the layout renders. I also can't access it from nested layouts. If the volume selector layout loads the volumes in props, the nested layouts that shows notes can't access that because I can't directly pass my props to it without setting it somewhere else accessible from both places as rendering that component/layout is done by Sveltekit.

I tried putting state in `session`, but that can only be changed client-side and I can't SSR what's selected then.

I tried putting state in `page.stuff` but that's read-only outside of `load`, so again I can't update it if I add a new series or volume.

I've got a mix of this and it's super buggy. Any advice? If I was writing a normal SPA I'd just store these in a few stores but in SSR that becomes global state, which is why I'm trying to figure out a workaround here.

Comment: already tried it with stores?

Comment: @Faulander I hadn't tried it, but judging from the Sveltekit docs it seemed like it might have unintended side effects if I just import a store from anywhere "Mutating any shared state on the server will affect all clients, not just the current one." I haven't tried it yet but I'm thinking of making a store to use with setContext, as that's scoped to the component instead of just globally available as an import.

Comment: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores the comment about context here is where I got the idea.